# SQL - Getting duplicate list based on value from multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, sorry if the title is misleading, so i make this example.

Table : data_list

Column : Serial, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5

Datas :

- 381, 0, 0, 0, 125, 99
- 537, 10002, 1234, 0, 0, 0
- 931, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
- 1213, 123, 100, 0, 0, 10002
- 1437, 7361, 918, 17823, 0, 0
- 7777, 0, 0, 100, 0, 1234
- 7951, 125, 0, 0, 918, 0

From above example, i want the result to be :

- 381

  ```
  because there is duplicate value 125 from serial 7951
  ```
- 537

  ```
  because there is duplicate value 10002 from serial 1213
  ```
- 1213

  ```
  because there is duplicate value 10002 from serial 537
  ```
- 7777

  ```
  because there is duplicate value 100 from serial 1213
  ```
- 7951

  ```
  because there is duplicate value 125 from serial 381, and value 918 from serial 1437
  ```

**value 0 not counted as duplicate**

I have tried several logic, also from others question from stackoverflow. Still i cant figure it out.

Anyone can help? thanks

Comment: Please include your sql(s) so that we can see what has been tried.  Have you done UNION?  Select Serial, A1 as Ax Union Select Serial, A2 Union ....  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would unpivot and use window functions:

```
select dl.serial, v.a
from (select dl.serial, v.a, count(*) over (partition by v.a) as cnt
      from data_list dl cross apply
           (values (dl.a1), (dl.a2), (dl.a3), (dl.a4), (dl.a5)
           ) v(a)
      where v.a <> 0
     ) dl
where cnt > 1;
```

The above version runs the risk of returning a duplicate `serial` even if the duplicate is within a single row.  If that is a possibility, it can be easily modified.  Although SQL Server does not support `count(distinct)` as a window function, it is easy to emulate with `dense_rank()`:

```
select dl.serial, v.a
from (select dl.serial, v.a,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by v.a order by dl.seral asc) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by v.a order by dl.seral desc)
             ) as cnt
      from data_list dl cross apply
           (values (dl.a1), (dl.a2), (dl.a3), (dl.a4), (dl.a5)
           ) v(a)
      where v.a <> 0
     ) dl
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: this is the best answer, its show the "serial" also the "a". i learn something new about "cross apply". thank you @gordon

Answer (score 4):

Normalize (Un-Flatten) the A1, A2... into a single set, look for multiples, and get their Serial.

```
With findDupesUnion as (
    Select Serial, A1 as Ax From findDupes Where A1 <> 0
    Union
    Select Serial, A2 as Ax From findDupes Where A2 <> 0
    Union
    Select Serial, A3 as Ax From findDupes Where A3 <> 0
    Union
    Select Serial, A4 as Ax From findDupes Where A4 <> 0
    Union
    Select Serial, A5 as Ax From findDupes Where A5 <> 0
)

Select distinct Serial From findDupesUnion
where Ax in 
(
Select Ax From findDupesUnion
group by Ax
having COUNT(*) > 1
)
Order By Serial
```

Comment: this one good and correct answer, but i really not familiar with "WITH", but this one solve my problem also, like Oliver and Gordon answer

Comment: @LearnMore CTE (Common Table Expression) is like a sub-query or a view, and begins by using WITH CTEname AS (some sql)  Select ... From CTEname ....  The CTE can be accessed multiple times in the main query.  (from MS SQLServer book, p.259)

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty is that the data is not normalized. I.e. you have columns A1, A2, A3, A4, A5. This requires you to treat each one of these columns individually.

This is my query.

```
SELECT a.Serial
FROM data_list a
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT b.Serial FROM data_list b
      WHERE
         b.Serial <> a.Serial AND
         ( b.A1 <> 0 AND b.A1 IN (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a.A5) OR
           b.A2 <> 0 AND b.A2 IN (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a.A5) OR
           b.A3 <> 0 AND b.A3 IN (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a.A5) OR
           b.A4 <> 0 AND b.A4 IN (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a.A5) OR
           b.A5 <> 0 AND b.A5 IN (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4, a.A5) )
    )
```

It compares each row from `data_list` to each row of the same `data_list` in a sub-query. To distinguish the two references, I gave them the aliases `a` and `b`.

`b.Serial <> a.Serial` ensures that we don't compare a Serial to itself.

Because you are obviously not interested in duplicate 0 values, it tests also for `b.A1 <> 0`, `b.A2 <> 0` etc.

See result here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff82ce/2/0

The result also contains the Serial 1437, because the value 918 is also contained in Serial 7951.

Comment: for me, this answer is the most easier to understand, because its stored in array (IN), while i didnt think of that before (since i was rarely use the IN).